# Graph Link Prediction Accuracy

Tags: charts, graph-theory

A Stochastic Block Model (SBM) is a random graph model with a block structure. Given parameters n ∈ Z+, k ∈ Z+, α ∈ [0, 1], and β ∈ [0, 1], the model works as follows. Create k groups of vertices with n members each. Connect pairs of vertices within the same group uniformly at random with probability α and pairs across groups uniformly at random with probability β. Your goal is to solve the link prediction problem for a graph generated using SBM. More specifically, given a pair of nodes in the graph, your model should predict whether the pair is connected (link) or not (i.e., binary classification) based on the remaining pairs. Notice that the output of the SBM includes only the graph but not the group assignments.

Provide an upper bound on the accuracy (fraction of correct predictions) of the best link prediction algorithm for expected case (number of edges within and across groups) for each of the following specific cases:

1. α = .6 and β = .0
2. α = .6 and β = .1
3. α = .4 and β = .1
   Hint: you can assume that the best algorithm can recover all the parameters of the SBM from the data

I am just having a lot of problem understanding what the question is asking?

I keep circling around to thinking how the probability of edges is going to translate to the accuracy of predictions themselves? Would the upper bound be a 100 for every case? the best model would predict all edges correctly?

Comment: This may be better fitting on StackExchange Mathematics, with a bit more explanation